# Declaring vector type as struct in same struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

can we declare vector with a struct inside this struct?

```
    struct foo {
       int a;
       vector<foo>;
    }
```

Or is there any work around for this?

Comment: Need to vector <foo> v; You need to have variable name.

Comment: For a work-around have a look at [boost containers of incomplete types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types).